# Aloha Editor | Link plugin: edit class

Tags: plugins, hyperlink, aloha-editor

I'm working with AlohaEditor and I try to make class attr to be editable for link plugin. In sidebar I can edit target and title, but I need also to edit class. Does anyone know how to do this?